# JavaScript Code that redirect to a domain if published on a different domain?

Tags: javascript

A few years ago I came across a piece of code that will redirect the page to a certain domain name.

For example, I put the code in on of my `.js` files and somebody tries to rip my site, and publish it to their own domain, it will redirect them to my domain.

Comment: If someone copies your JS, they will just change your domain with theirs. You can't prevent people from copying your JS and modifying it. Or are you only trying to prevent hotlinking?

Answer (score 0):

So you can't find this code now, and you want us to replicate it? Fine.

```
/(?:^|\.)example\.com$/.test(location.host) || (location.href = '//example.com')
```

That should do the trick, and it won't redirect when on subdomains. Take care to escape all periods as `\.` when substituting your own domain, because they otherwise have a special meaning (matching almost anything) in regular expressions.

Comment: `fakeexample.com` would match the above because of the "\.?"

Comment: Thanks, gyre. I will test it. Also, I searched for many hours to find it but to no avail. Believe me, this was my last option.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I tested it myself, so it should.